# How to modify a vb app without sourcecode?

Tags: vb6

I want to modify a simple vb app(.exe), but I have no source code about it.
The app has a button and a textbox, when the button clicked, the textbox will be set with "7:00" and then down to "0:00".

Now, I want to do a small modification to this app: when the button clicked, don't set textbox with "7:00" but with "5:00".

Can anyone tell me how to implement it?

Comment: If it's that simple, you might as well just re-implement it yourself. Then you'll have the source code.

Comment: My app is VB, not VB.Net.
But i can not re-implement it, because this app has some other forms beside i just mentioned:(

Comment: I think that Anon meant for you to re-implement the entire project, not just the one form.

Comment: Oh.... the whole project is somewhat complex to re-implement:(

Answer (score 1):

1. Fire up your favourite hex editor
2. Look for the string `7:00` in the `.exe` file
3. Replace it with `5:00`.
4. Hope for the best.

Comment: I'd also try a text search for "7:00" on your hard drive.  It could be in an ini file.  Also check around the registry too.

Comment: Thanks for your help i have search for "7:00" in hex and harddrive, but i can not find it

Comment: Did you look for UTF-16 strings too?

Comment: I have search for the string in the hex editor, but i can not found at all. i am afraid of that maybe the app use a int value to record time and convert it to datatime sting and show it on textbox:(

Answer (score 0):

Use [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) against the .exe file to get to the source code. Copy and paste into class files in new vb project. Confirm the app still functions as the original. Now make your change.

This assumes the source code hasn't been obfuscated.

Comment: can reflector give me source code, i have tried some similiar tools, but those tool can only give me some froms and icons, but no source code:(

Comment: I believe Reflector is for .NET assemblies. I'm not aware of a version that works on  'classic' VB.

Comment: The question said winforms app. I automatically assumed .NET